# OpenCV Failed Compilation "Eigen/Core: No such file or directory" -- Cannot Change CMake Entry

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to install OpenCV but when I try to compile using CMake, I always get the error stated in the question, usually around 4% - 6%.

```
[  6%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles

/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
In file included from /home/joey/opencv/opencv/opencv/modules/core/test/test_precomp.hpp:12:0,
                 from /home/joey/opencv/opencv/build/modules/core/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/home/joey/opencv/opencv/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:66:12: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
 #  include <Eigen/Core>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1229: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

So, after some Googling, I decided that I just need to change where CMake is going for Eigen. Using cmake-gui I changed Eigen3_DIR from /usr/lib/cmake/eigen3 to /usr/include/eigen3, at the advice of answers from similar questions (not exactly similar; they just recommended a path change and gave the latter path). **The problem comes in when I hit configure or try to generate: CMake reverts the entry back to the former.** I tried looking at some of the CMake files (CMakeCache.txt, CMakeLists.txt) but I really don't know what I'm looking at so I figured I'd ask people more knowledgeable than me. I've also looked in both paths, and in both cases the desired files exist -- eigen3/Eigen/(header files) and eigen3/(cmake config files).

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried installing in two directories: once in ~/opencv and another in /mnt/Linux/opencv. In each compile attempt, I delete the build files and rebuild OpenCV. Both have yielded the same results. I've also tried deleting and re-cloning the source, starting from scratch several times to no avail.

What's going on? Am I missing settings, or even focusing on the problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated, guided or fed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably kinda hackish, but I fixed it:

[What led me to the fix](https://github.com/facebookarchive/caffe2/issues/738)--it's not OpenCV but it's the same sort of problem.

In cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake, I commented out this part of the Eigen block:

```
#if(TARGET Eigen3::Eigen)
  # Use Eigen3 imported target if possible
  #list(APPEND OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS Eigen3::Eigen)
  #set(HAVE_EIGEN 1)
```

as well as changed the find_package call to

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.0.0)
```

The full Eigen block of code:

```
if(WITH_EIGEN AND NOT HAVE_EIGEN)
  find_package(Eigen3 3.0.0)
  if(Eigen3_FOUND)
    #if(TARGET Eigen3::Eigen)
      # Use Eigen3 imported target if possible
      #list(APPEND OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS Eigen3::Eigen)
      #set(HAVE_EIGEN 1)
    else()
      if(DEFINED EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
        set(EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
        set(HAVE_EIGEN 1)
      elseif(DEFINED EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)
        set(EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
        set(HAVE_EIGEN 1)
      endif()
    #endif()
    if(HAVE_EIGEN)
      if(DEFINED EIGEN3_WORLD_VERSION)  # CMake module
        set(EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION ${EIGEN3_WORLD_VERSION})
        set(EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION ${EIGEN3_MAJOR_VERSION})
        set(EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION ${EIGEN3_MINOR_VERSION})
      else()  # Eigen config file
        set(EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION ${EIGEN3_VERSION_MAJOR})
        set(EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION ${EIGEN3_VERSION_MINOR})
        set(EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION ${EIGEN3_VERSION_PATCH})
      endif()

  if(NOT HAVE_EIGEN)
    if(NOT EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH OR NOT EXISTS "${EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH}")
      set(__find_paths "")
      set(__find_path_extra_options "")
      if(NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
        list(APPEND __find_paths /opt)
      endif()
      if(DEFINED ENV{EIGEN_ROOT})
        set(__find_paths "$ENV{EIGEN_ROOT}/include")
        list(APPEND __find_path_extra_options NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
      else()
        set(__find_paths ENV ProgramFiles ENV ProgramW6432)
      endif()
      find_path(EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH "Eigen/Core"
                PATHS ${__find_paths}
                PATH_SUFFIXES include/eigen3 include/eigen2 Eigen/include/eigen3 Eigen/include/eigen2
                DOC "The path to Eigen3/Eigen2 headers"
                ${__find_path_extra_options}
      )
    endif()
    if(EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH AND EXISTS "${EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH}")
      ocv_parse_header("${EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH}/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h" EIGEN_VERSION_LINES EIGE$
      set(HAVE_EIGEN 1)
    endif()
  endif()
endif()
if(HAVE_EIGEN)
  if(EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH AND EXISTS "${EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH}")
    ocv_include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH})
  endif()
endif()
```

For whatever reason, the commented out section was passing the check (Eigen3_FOUND) but didn't provide any working path for OpenCV. I've a limited knowledge of CMake (first time messing with CMake code), so I really don't know what I did or any of the repercussions that might come of it. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the cloned Eigen directory directly. You will need to prepare build files with CMake and then add the build folder to Eigen3_DIR and the install/include folder to EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH.